# Using Expose with class-transformer

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-transformer

I want to achieve a rather simple goal: convert one prop's on my response DTO.

**`refund-order.response.dto.ts`**

```
export class RefundOrderResponseDto {
    @Expose({ name: 'order_reference' })
    orderReference: string;
}
```

What I want is the response to look so: `{ order_reference: 'd6c1dcf3-ef7b-4fe7-9e93-147a39a43a01' }`, the field name should be `order_reference` and not `orderReference`.

On my controller I tried different things, some of them are more sensible than others.

But this `Expose` decorator does not do the transformation. I would expect the `Expose` decorator to rename the field, that would be logical.

In very abstract terms, the refund method on the controller is something like this:

```
    @Post('refund')
    async refundPayment(
        @Body() requestRefundDto: RequestRefundDto,
    ): Promise<RefundOrderResponseDto> {
        // call to the refundService to get refundResult;
        const response = new RefundOrderResponseDto();
        response.orderReference = refundResult.reference;
        return response;
    }
```

Also, instead of doing this:

```
        const response = new RefundOrderResponseDto();
        response.orderReference = refundResult.reference;
```

I could have just returned:

```
return { orderReference: refundResult.reference };
```

But it does not help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out that for this to work, I need to
make use of `ClassSerializerInterceptor` like so `@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)`;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).